# Save Function Problems in Python

Tags: python, save, pygame, paint

I am currently trying to create a save feature for my paint program that I am creating using python 2.7.5 and pygame.  Here is my code:

```
from pygame import *
from random import *
from glob import *
from math import *

def getName():
    ans = ""                    # final answer will be built one letter at a time.
    arialFont = font.SysFont("Times New Roman", 16)
    back = screen.copy()        # copy screen so we can replace it when done
    textArea = Rect(5,5,200,25) # make changes here.

    pics = glob("*.bmp")+glob("*.jpg")+glob("*.png")
    n = len(pics)
    choiceArea = Rect(textArea.x,textArea.y+textArea.height,textArea.width,n*textArea.height)
    draw.rect(screen,(220,220,220),choiceArea)        # draw the text window and the text.
    draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),choiceArea,1)        # draw the text window and the text.
    for i in range(n):
        txtPic = arialFont.render(pics[i], True, (0,111,0))   #
        screen.blit(txtPic,(textArea.x+3,textArea.height*i+choiceArea.y))

typing = True
while typing:
    for e in event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            event.post(e)   # puts QUIT back in event list so main quits
            return ""
        if e.type == KEYDOWN:
            if e.key == K_BACKSPACE:    # remove last letter
                if len(ans)>0:
                    ans = ans[:-1]
            elif e.key == K_KP_ENTER or e.key == K_RETURN : 
                typing = False
            elif e.key < 256:
                ans += e.unicode       # add character to ans

    txtPic = arialFont.render(ans, True, (0,0,0))   #
    draw.rect(screen,(220,255,220),textArea)        # draw the text window and the text.
    draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),textArea,2)            #
    screen.blit(txtPic,(textArea.x+3,textArea.y+2))

    display.flip()

screen.blit(back,(0,0))
return ans
```

I do not think there is a problem with the code above because the error message occurs in the following code:

```
if saveRect.collidepoint(mx,my):
        txt = getName(True)
        image.save(screen.subsurface(canvas),txt)
```

Here is the error message I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Wisdom1\Desktop\Comp Science Files\Canvas_(2).py", line 276, in <module>
txt = getName(True)
TypeError: getName() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with this error.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Why did you add in all that code if its not the right bit? What is the rest of the code around where the error is occuring, how is `image` being defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
pygame.image.save(screen.subsurface(canvas),txt)
```

By the way, the way variable `txt` is set does not look right right here. It is supposed to be a filename. But `getName`, in your code example, is a function.

Comment: add 'import pygame' at the beginning of your file